# Compare List with tuples against list and return unique tuples

Tags: python, list, rest, soap, tuples

Ok so I have been going at this for a bit, I am still getting my chops with python and this seems to be beyond me for the moment. I have a list of tuples and plain old list (could be wrong on the exact terminology, if so please let me know how to correctly state it. I like learning). I am trying to compare a value in each tuple against the values in the list and return all the unique tuples. So here is my code (modified as some of this is internal type stuff):

```
from suds.client import Client
from suds.transport.https import WindowsHttpAuthenticated
import requests, base64


soapurl = 'soapurl'
username = base64.b64decode('base64codehere').split(':')[0]
password = base64.b64decode('base64codehere').split(':')[1]
apiuser = base64.b64decode('differentbase64codehere').split(':')[0]
apipass = base64.b64decode('differentbase64codehere').split(':')[1]
ntlm = WindowsHttpAuthenticated(username=username, password=password)
client = Client(soapurl, transport=ntlm)
result = client.service.method(serverName='a1bcefg')
soapfiltered = []
for item in result[0]:
    soapfiltered.extend(list(item[i] for i in [0, 1, 6, 7]))
soapfiltered = zip(*[iter(soapfiltered)]*4)
apifiltered = []
for i in range(0, 11000, 1000):
    apiUrl = 'apiurl/?sort=id&limit=0&offset=' + str(i) +'&order=desc'
    apiData = requests.get(apiUrl, verify=False, auth=(apiuser, apipass)).json()
    for response in apiData['data']:
        apifiltered.append(str(response['hostname']))
```

Which basically gives me this:

apifiltered (limiting output as there is almost 3.8k reponse in apifiltered)

```
['A1BCEFG001', 'A1BCEFG339', 'A1BCEFGDED444', 'A1BCEFG343', 'A1BCEFG2700', 'A1BCEFG1133', 'A1BCEFGDED321', 'A1BCEFG347', 'A1BCEFG371', 'A1BCEFG373']
```

and

soapfiltered (limiting output as there is about 4k response in soapfiltered)

```
[(63258, A1BCEFG001, A5001195, Live), (63259, A1BCEFGDED444, A5001196, Live), (63260, A1BCEFGDED321, A5001194, Live), (63261, A1BCEFGDED2743, A5001199, Live), (63262, A1BCEFG339, A5001193, Live), (63263, A1BCEFGDED2745, A5001197, Live), (63264, A1BCEFGDED2746, A5001206, Live), (63265, A1BCEFGDED2747, A5001202, Live), (63266, A1BCEFGDED2748, A5001205, Live), (63387, A1BCEFG1193, A5004312, Live)]
```

So what I am trying to accomplish, if at all possible, is something like this:

```
[(63261, A1BCEFGDED2743, A5001199, Live), (63263, A1BCEFGDED2745, A5001197, Live), (63264, A1BCEFGDED2746, A5001206, Live), (63265, A1BCEFGDED2747, A5001202, Live), (63266, A1BCEFGDED2748, A5001205, Live), (63387, A1BCEFG1193, A5004312, Live)]
```

I have looked at other solutions but I cannot seem to get the results I am looking for. Any help would be appreciated as I continue to work on it from my end. If there is any additional information needed please ask and I will provide what I can. Thank you.

**EDIT FOR CLARIFICATION (TLDR;):**
I have a list:

```
apifiltered = ['A1BCEFG001', 'A1BCEFG339', 'A1BCEFGDED444', 'A1BCEFG343', 'A1BCEFG2700', 'A1BCEFG1133', 'A1BCEFGDED321', 'A1BCEFG347', 'A1BCEFG371', 'A1BCEFG373']
```

And a list of tuples:

```
soapfiltered = [(63258, A1BCEFG001, A5001195, Live), (63259, A1BCEFGDED444, A5001196, Live), (63260, A1BCEFGDED321, A5001194, Live), (63261, A1BCEFGDED2743, A5001199, Live), (63262, A1BCEFG339, A5001193, Live), (63263, A1BCEFGDED2745, A5001197, Live), (63264, A1BCEFGDED2746, A5001206, Live), (63265, A1BCEFGDED2747, A5001202, Live), (63266, A1BCEFGDED2748, A5001205, Live), (63387, A1BCEFG1193, A5004312, Live)]
```

I want to compare soapfiltered against apifiltered and remove any of the tuples from soapfiltered where the [1] value from each tuple in soapfiltered matches a value found in apifiltered.

Expected result:

```
expected = [(63261, A1BCEFGDED2743, A5001199, Live), (63263, A1BCEFGDED2745, A5001197, Live), (63264, A1BCEFGDED2746, A5001206, Live), (63265, A1BCEFGDED2747, A5001202, Live), (63266, A1BCEFGDED2748, A5001205, Live), (63387, A1BCEFG1193, A5004312, Live)]
```

**YET ANOTHER EDIT:**

@szabad gave a great answer:

```
expected = [tup for tup in smdbfiltered if tup[1] not in apifiltered]
```

So this works awesome, but there are tuples where tup[3] is something other than 'Live' like the following:

```
[(56536, A1BCEFG744-r, Retired, Prod 1CP)]
```

I need to drop these from the expected result as well. Can someone provide a solution that encompases the first issue and this issue?

Comment: It's hard to understand exactly what you are trying to do. Maybe you could post a much simpler example of the problem you are trying to solve? Because of all the ABC-like strings, it's hard to see immediately what you are [wanting to] do.

Comment: Can you clarify the test tuple vs. list you want to make? What's "unique" for you? Just forget about how you build your list and tuples - can you provide an example with plain, easy values?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, this should work: `soapfiltered = [tup for tup in soapfiltered if tup[1] not in apifiltered]`. This list-comprehension operation basically removes any tuples that have the value in position 1 in the `apifiltered` list.

Comment: @szabad that worked. You are a god among men. Is there also a way to filter out any that are not Live? Some of the tuples will end with tup[3] being something other than 'Live' and I need to drop those as well. Again thank you for the help you have rendered thus far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 filtered = [tup for tup in soapfiltered if tup[3] == 'Live' and tup[1] not in apifiltered]
```

Comment: And we have a winner. Thank you so much, I appreciate it more than you can know. Stay golden.